# Bootstrap datetimepicker - date based on input value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker and cannot figure out how to set the initial datetime when the page is loaded based on the input's value attribute.

When the page loads, the input is blank even though the field has a value.

```
<input type="text" name="start" id="start" value="2015-09-26 18:00"/>
```

JS -

```
$("#start").datetimepicker({
                ignoreReadonly: true,
                useCurrent: false,
                sideBySide: true,
                format: "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your date format is not the same as declared in datetimepicker settings object so change the datetimepicker date format:

```
    //format: "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"
    format: "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm"
```

you can also set the date using **setDate()** or **setLocalDate()**

```
    $("#start").data('datetimepicker').setDate(new Date(year, month, day, 00, 01));
    $("#start").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, 00, 01));
```

---

another option is to pass **defaultDate** when creating datetimepicker

```
    var dateNow = new Date();

    $("#start").datetimepicker({
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            useCurrent: false,
            sideBySide: true,
            format: "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm",
            defaultDate:dateNow
        });
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Silly me, of course the formats did not match - that did the trick. Thanks so much!